# Forums in Django - which of these apps would be easiest to implement in this scenario?

Tags: django, forums

I want to do something a bit like they have on IMDb - every film and every person has a forum dedicated just to them. I also want to have a forum on the main message boards, which would show all the threads from the film pages and another forum for all the threads from the people pages.

I've been looking at [DjangoBB](http://djangobb.org/), [Dinette](http://uswaretech.com/forum/) and [Sphene (SCT)](http://sct.sphene.net/wiki/show/Start/). DjangoBB looks like it has the most features and it's very elegant. Dinette doesn't seem that far behind. Sphene has a few disadvantages - less features I think and it makes me dependent on Sphene's Community app, but it seems like it might be the easiest to use in my scenario - I've seen examples of Sphene being used in similar fashion.

I'm pretty sure all three can be made to do more or less what I want, but would love some opinions on what might work best for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider: you could just use [django-threadedcomments](http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/). It won't be as full-featured as installing a full forum solution, but has the advantage of being very compact and flexible -- basically, threaded comments can be attached to anything (a Person, a Film, etc).

It appears that DjangoBB and Dinette are not set up so that forums could attach themselves to a record in this fashion. Not sure about Sphene but it sounds like you'd have to use the entire community app.

I've set up a very, very simple Discussion app that could perform what you want. If you're interested let me know and I'll put it up on github for you to take a look at. Note that it's not at all full-featured like the ones you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, worth considering. But I think in the long run, it's much too simple for me... I need something a bit more fully-fledged.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer this, but I think it might be worth mentioning [The Pinax Project](http://pinaxproject.com/), which is django-based and is geared toward rapid development of social websites with many applications integrated together and customizeable at the user-level.